# What is the logic behind Media types' type+subtype combinations?

Tags: type, media

I am a bit confused by the nesting that occurs in [Media types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) (also known as their former name 'MIME types'):

The top level types are called `application`, `text`, `image` `video`, `audio`, `message`, `model` and a couple of others. However, it is not clear to me why certain subtypes are nested under one of these, while other subtypes are nested under a different one:

- Datastructures: Why `application/json` but `text/csv`? And why does `xml` appear both as `application/xml` and `text/xml`? And why are these not in `message/*` or `model/*`, which at least on a surface level seem to fit 'encoded datastructure' better?
- Languages: Why `application/javascript` but `text/html` and `text/css`?
- Why is there both `application/xml` and `text/xml`?

In an effort to make this a clear, objective question, maybe the question might be best phrased as: **What are the rules that determine in which type a 'Media-type'-subtype will be placed, and why are there some 'duplicates'?**

Comment: See [RFC 2046](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046) for the definition of top-level media types: “text” is for human-readable formats, “application” for formats that are supposed to be processed by some application. Human-readable data interchange formats like XML or JSON can be seen as either.